# Which header should we choose for modal dialogs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, accessibility

Headers should represent the page's structure and be nested accordingly. [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/#exception-for-fixed-page-sections) states the following:

> **Exception for fixed page sections**
>
> In fixed sections of the page, for example in sidebars, the heading ranks should not change depending on the ranks in the content area. In those cases, consistency across pages is more important.

Is this also true for modal dialogs? They usually aren't part of the actual page structure after all. Which header should we use for modal dialogs?

Bootstrap seems to [always use h5s](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#examples).

As an example we use a bootstrap modal in our footer which displays additional information about our application's version:

```html
<div id="v-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Version</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Copyright © 2020 Foobar</p>
      <p>Version 1.3.7124.19131</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In an a11y test we recently received this was marked as a potential issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the upcoming changes in HTML 5.1 (where we don't know if multiple `H1`s will still be valid and where within HTML) I always recommend one `<h1>` per page at all times for accessibility (and SEO) as that is the long standing and accepted practice.

This makes the answer in your circumstances to use a `<h2>`.

I recommend this as your modal sits outside of the flow of the rest of the document and so it logically should be a 'top level' heading level.

The only exception to this is if your modal is within the flow of your document, at that point it would probably be best to use an appropriate `<h>` level that fits with it's position in the document flow.

Although I am not sure why anyone would want a modal within the flow of the document as that is not a good practice in the first place.

Comment: This is a correct and well informed answer. Perhaps it is pure conjecture on my part, but I find it hard to believe that either search engines or W3 will penalize coders for multiple H1 elements moving forward. The exception quoted above dates from April 2017 and is en established norm among accessibility-conscious developers. Without the exception, gaps in the heading sequence would be troubling to screen reader users. We know that such users rely on headings above any other means of navigation. (https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#finding)

Comment: It is always tough to know what they will and wont penalise for, at the end of the day if they do penalise it will be 0.1% of overall score and not important in that respect. I just let accessibility guide me when I am unsure and normally that fixes my semantics and my SEO all at once. That link is a useful one to add to my arsenal so thanks for that, i have even read that document before and must have blanked it out :-P